# Эффект печати сообщения в telegram bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telebot

Как сделать эффект, будто бот печатает сообщение?
Вот пример моего кода:

```
import telebot
from functools import wraps
from telegram import (ChatAction)

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TELEGRAM_API")

# Функция, отображающая ввод сообщения
def send_typing_action(func):
    """Отправляет действие ввода при обработке команды func"""
    @wraps(func)
    def command_func(update, context, *args, **kwargs):
        context.bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=update.effective_message.chat_id, action=ChatAction.TYPING)
        return func(update, context,  *args, **kwargs)
    return command_func
@send_typing_action
def my_handler(update, context):
    pass

# Функция, обрабатывающая команду /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(m, res=False):
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, text=f'Привет, <b>{m.from_user.first_name} {m.from_user.last_name}</b>!'f'\nДавай говорить!'.format(m.from_user), parse_mode='html')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете telebot как обёртку для API, то эта строчка поможет вам создать иллюзию печати ботом:

```
bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'typing')
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=chat_id, action=telegram.ChatAction.TYPING)
```

Comment: chat_id - это чат ид бота?

Comment: если chat_id принадлежит боту, то не работает